# String Replacements from Values in Assoc Array

Tags: php, preg-replace, associative-array, str-replace, preg-replace-callback

I'm given a string of HTML with some "tokens" in it.  They are structured like `{:TOKEN_NAME:}`

For instance:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    {:TITLE:}
    {:DESCRIPTION:}
    {:KEYWORDS:}
    {:GOOGLE-VERIFY:}
    {:BING-VERIFY:}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/base.styles.css?_=<?php echo time(); ?>" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/custom.css?_=<?php echo time(); ?>" type="text/css" />     

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <article data-role="page-wrapper" class="container-fluid">
        <header class="row-fluid" data-role="page-header">
            <h1 class="span5 logo pull-right"><a href="http://www.o7thwebdesign.com">o7th Web Design</a></h1>
            <nav class="span7">
                {:PAGE-CONTENT:}
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section class="row-fluid" data-role="page-container">

        </section>
        <footer class="row-fluid" data-role="page-footer">

        </footer>
    </article>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/scripts.js?_=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/custom.js?_=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
    {:GOOGLE-UA:}
</body>
</html>
```

I am also given an associative array, with the token names, and what they should be replaced with, as such:

```
    // Populate and pull all global smarttags
    private function PullGlobalSmartTags($values){
        return array(array('Name'=>'{:TITLE:}', 'Replacement'=>'<title>' . $values[0] . '</title>'),
                     array('Name'=>'{:DESCRIPTION:}', 'Replacement'=>'<meta name="description" content="' . $values[1] . '" />'),
                     array('Name'=>'{:KEYWORDS:}', 'Replacement'=>($values[22]) ? null : '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $values[2] . '" />'),
                     array('Name'=>'{:GOOGLE-UA:}', 'Replacement'=>'<script type="text/javascript">var _gaq = _gaq || [];_gaq.push([\'_setAccount\', \'' . $values[3] . '\']);_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\']);(function(){var ga = document.createElement(\'script\');ga.type = \'text/javascript\'; ga.async = true;ga.src = (\'https:\' == document.location.protocol ? \'https://ssl\' : \'http://www\') + \'.google-analytics.com/ga.js\';var s = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();</script>'),
                     array('Name'=>'{:GOOGLE-VERIFY:}', 'Replacement'=>'<meta name="google-site-verification" content="' . $values[4] . '" />'),
                     array('Name'=>'{:BING-VERIFY:}', 'Replacement'=>'<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="' . $values[5] . '" />'),
                     array('Name'=>'{:PAGE-CONTENT:}', 'Replacement'=>$values[6]),);
    }
```

Please assume all values in `$values` populate, and populate correctly (because they do...)

I know with str_replace, and preg_replace I can simply pass arrays in as my needle, replacement, and haystack, however everything I am seeing only shows non-associative arrays.

My question is, how can I do these replacements?   I know that I could simply loop through the array, and do my replacements one at a time, but is there a way to do this without looping?

This does do the trick:

```
        for($i=0; $i<$gsCt; ++$i){
            $rettemp = str_replace($GlobalSmartTags[$i]['Name'], $GlobalSmartTags[$i]['Replacement'], $rettemp);
        }
```

however, I do not believe it is the most efficient method to do this.

Comment: I don't need to search anything, please re-read the question

Comment: which php version are you using?

Comment: PHP 5.4 (or whatever the latest one is), my server's up-to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$replace = PullGlobalSmartTags($values);
str_replace(array_column($replace, 'Name'), array_column($replace,'Replacement'), $html);
```

This only works with PHP 5 >= 5.5.0. Reference: [array_column](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Here is couple of suggestion till you upgrade to 5.5.0.

You can convert your replace array to single dimension array like this and replace.

```
$replace = PullGlobalSmartTags($value);
$kv = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($replace);$i++){
    $kv[$replace[$i]['Name']]=$replace[$i]['Replacement'];
}
$rettemp = str_replace(array_keys($kv),array_values($kv),$rettemp);
```

Or you can change the function PullGlobalSmartTags to return single dimension array and use str_replace as above. You can even use the method you suggested, but it has much more replace in a loop.

I won't suggest compiling from code on production server unless there is an absolute necessity.

Comment: 5.4.9 is the latest stable version, that's what I've got running

Comment: I've upgraded my server.  And it still shows that 5.4.9 is the latest version.  I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 server, and no, I will not compile from source

Comment: don't mean to blow you off, I will hopefully be able to get around to trying that later on, if not tomorrow first thing.  Thanks for sticking this out :)

Comment: Works good.  I'll have to bookmark this q, for when my server can get PHP5.5 though, seems like that array_column would make it more efficient even further.   Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

`strtr()` will very happily consume a flat associative array of needle-replacement pairs -- use `array_column()` to prepare/reduce the array structure.

```
echo strtr(
         $rettemp,
         array_column( 
             $GlobalSmartTags,
             'Replacement',  // column to become values
             'Name'  // column to become keys
         )
     );
```